# Troubleshooting random computer freezes

Tags: linux, freeze, troubleshooting

In the last two months, I've experienced random freezes in my computer a couple of times. I use Linux, and the computer is a desktop computer with an AMD Ryzen CPU, ASUS Prime motherboard and Nvidia graphics. This is what happens:

- I'm working normally and the screen suddenly goes black, and after a couple of seconds, the "No HDMI signal" appears
- The computer is still on, I can see the lights and hear the fans running in the desktop tower
- Apparently, I can't do anything with the keyboard (I tried Magic-SysRq, etc)
- I can't power off the computer using the power button. No matter if I press it for two seconds, ten or thirty. I just had to cut the power using the toggle in the back to be able to power it on again
- After reboot, I couldn't see anything meaningful in the system logs (systemd), or at least I don't know what to search for

I haven't detected any common pattern in the two times that this has happened other than VirtualBox was running. Temperature is still not very high here in this time of the year.

I'd like to know how to troubleshot this to first know if it's a software problem or a hardware fault. But now, I'm clueless.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Find another system, even a smartphone, and see if you can ssh into it, then run some diagnostics.

Comment: You could run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) overnight. This is a good hardware test.

Comment: I guess I won't be able to ssh into it, as it looks unresponsive (as the power button does not work anymore), but I'll try. I'll try memtest too, but I thought some defective RAM module wouldn't just freeze the computer this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it might be a HD issue. Run a SMART test on your hard drive. If your system is still running, it could be that you have bad sectors on your HD.

So a brief command you can run to do a quick check is:

```
sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda (or whatever your real HD dev path is)
```

This identical issue has happened to me before and sadly still does because I have not swapped out  the bad HD. But in my case, for some odd reason the freezing happens during the night and rarely have caught it freeze mid-day. Since it's my server that freezes, the login screen cursor just stops blinking and when force rebooting - journalctl shows a lot of HD errors.

So it might also be a good idea to setup SMART monitoring on your HD's so this doesn't happen to you again - https://linuxman.co/linux-server/staying-up-to-date-with-your-hard-drive-with-smartmon-tools/